# Sum data by week in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table (Oracle 11g) that contains hours of overtime worked (WRK_HR) and the date worked (CHRG_DT). I want to build a stored procedure that returns the sum of WRK_HR for Saturday through Friday, each Friday, from the start of the project to the date provided. Say my table contains the following:

```
CHRG_DT   WRK_HR
--------  ------
01/01/14       4
01/02/14       8
01/15/14       7
```

My output should look like this (each date is a Friday):

```
CHRG_DT   TOTAL
--------  -----
01/03/14     12
01/10/14     12
01/17/14     19
```

Here is the SQL I have:

```
PROCEDURE GET_OVERTIME(  
  p_chrg_dt IN VARCHAR2,  
  cur OUT sys_refcursor  
)  
IS  
BEGIN  
OPEN cur FOR  
  SELECT  
  TO_CHAR(CHRG_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS CHRG_DT,  
  SUM(WRK_HR) AS TOTAL  
  FROM OVERTIME
  WHERE TRUNC(CHRG_DT) <= TO_DATE(p_chrg_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  GROUP BY CHRG_DT
  ORDER BY CHRG_DT;
END;
```

Here is the result from my SQL. As you can see, it gives me a result for each unique day. I need it to total on every given Friday, even if there was no entry that Friday:

```
CHRG_DT   TOTAL
--------  -----
01/01/14      4
01/02/14     12
01/15/14     19
```

Comment: See if a modification of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110943/how-do-i-calulate-week-of-year-in-oracle-using-a-non-standard-first-day-of-the-w) will work.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to convert your day values to be the end-of-week, and select and group by that value.

Subtract one day from them, and use NEXT_DAY() to get the next friday ...

```
NEXT_DAY(CHRG_DT-1,'FRIDAY')
```

Answer (score 1):

With this set of test data....

```
 create table tq84_sum_data_by_week (
   chrg_dt   date,
   wrk_hr    number
 );

 insert into tq84_sum_data_by_week values (date '2014-01-01', 4);
 insert into tq84_sum_data_by_week values (date '2014-01-02', 8);
 insert into tq84_sum_data_by_week values (date '2014-01-15', 7);
```

... the following should do:

```
 with fridays as (
 --
 -- 1 First, we need to "create" all fridays that we want
 --   the report to sum on
 --
   select
 --
 -- 2 The first friday is 01/03/14
 --
     date '2014-01-03' + 
 --
 -- 3  The fridays are 7 days apart:
 --
    (level-1) * 7 date_
 --
   from dual
 --
 -- 4  Three fridays are sufficient
 --    for this small test.
 --
     connect by level <= 3
 )
 --
 select 
   fridays.date_,
 --
 -- 7  This expression does the 'cumulative sum':
 --
   sum(sum(weeks.wrk_hr)) over (order by fridays.date_)  total_hrs
 from 
 --
 -- 5  Since we want a record for *each* friday,
 --    we use a 'left join':
 --
   fridays               left   outer join
 --
   tq84_sum_data_by_week weeks
 --
 -- 6  next_day(..., 'friday') returns the next
 --    friday for a date which we need for the
 --    join:
 --
   on fridays.date_ = next_day(weeks.chrg_dt, 'friday')
 group by
   fridays.date_;
```

Cleaning up:

```
 drop table tq84_sum_data_by_week purge;
```

Same thing on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5854/1)